# Does syslinux switch to protected mode after loading the kernel?

Tags: kernel, bootloader

Does syslinux switch to protected mode after loading the kernel ? What is the machine state after syslinux boots a kernel.

Comment: Syslinux needs to access more memory than 640KB, so it will have to switch to protected mode already while loading the kernel (and initrd) from disk.

Comment: what would be the machine state, finally

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you are talking about syslinux loading a Linux kernel.

Take a look at [Documentation/x86/boot.txt](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=blob;f=Documentation/x86/boot.txt;h=9b7221a86df291e6c651e66a3bebc41c69256633;hb=61c4f2c81c61f73549928dfd9f3e8f26aa36a8cf).

The Linux kernel has a small real mode setup code (found at [arch/x86/boot/](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=tree;f=arch/x86/boot;h=7d33b13034b382ea85fdc123a846c032cff7d384;hb=61c4f2c81c61f73549928dfd9f3e8f26aa36a8cf)), which does a few things which must be done before the transition to protected mode (most of it querying the real mode BIOS for a few pieces of information). The bootloader loads this part in low memory (below 640k).

Older kernels were small enough to fit in the less than 640k of contiguous low memory, so the bootloader loaded the whole kernel in low memory, and could do everything in real mode. Newer kernels are bigger (usually around 4M), so they have to be loaded in high memory (above 1M). To do this, the bootloader has to change to protected mode to put the kernel there, changing back to real mode to call the BIOS to read more sectors from the disk, and *change back to real mode* before jumping to the kernel setup code (which will again transition to protected mode one last time).

So, to answer your question, it does the opposite: it switches *from* protected mode to real mode after loading the kernel.

The processor state is as described in the documentation I linked to above: real mode CS pointing to the start of the real mode setup code plus 0x20 (making CS:IP point to the start of the second 512-byte real mode setup code sector), the rest of the segment registers pointing to the start of the real mode setup code (the first sector), and several parameters filled in the headers found in the first two sectors of the real mode setup code. The content of the general-purpose registers does not matter.

Comment: For the linux kernel, it is okay, the machine should be in protected mode and the processor state as the linux boot protocol say. The context is for any general kernel, say a home made prototype, in that case what would be the case. Like for GRUB it will follow the Multiboot Specifications.